# can't figure out where to use await

Tags: javascript, async-await

Can't figure out whether to put await or not before verifyPassword...
if I remove await before verifyPassword the toast don't go off and programe run for infinity.

**onSubmit Function: **

```
onSubmit: async (values) => {
      let loginPromise = await verifyPassword({
        username: username,
        password: values.password,
      });

      toast.promise(loginPromise, {
        loading: "Checking...",
        success: <b> Login successfully...</b>,
        error: <b> Incorrect Password </b>,
      });

      loginPromise.then((res) => {
        let { token } = res.data;
        localStorage.setItem("token", token);
        navigate("/profile");
      });
    },
```

**verifyPassword function :**

```
//login function
export async function verifyPassword({ username, password }) {
  try {
    if (username) {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/login`, {
        username,
        password,
      });
      return Promise.resolve({ data });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject({ error: "Incorrect password ..." });
  }
}
```

---

I've applied await at other submit calls but it works perfectly.

```
 async function onSubmit(e) {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      let { status } = await verifyOTP({ username, code: OTP });
      if (status === 201) {
        toast.success("Verified successfully");
        return navigate("/reset");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return toast.error("Wrong OTP please try again!!!");
    }
  }
```

**verifyOTP function :**

```
// verify OTP
export async function verifyOTP({ username, code }) {
  try {
    const { data, status } = await axios.get("/api/verifyOTP", {
      params: { username, code },
    });
    return { data, status };
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject({ error });
  }
}
```

I put await at second line then toast shows (Checking...) and don't go off. I am new to React so I think once the verifyPassword resolve or reject promise then that loading message must go off but it doesn't. but if I remove await before verifyPassword then app works completely fine. Now I am confused where to use await.

Comment: usually, you `await` something that is/returns a `Promise`

Comment: `loginPromise` is not a promise.

Answer (score 1):

The `await` operator does not return a promise, so `loginPromise` is not a promise, but your data object. That means you are not passing a promise as first argument to `toast.promise`, and it also means that it has no `.then` method.

To fix this, don't use `await` here, but really get the promise returned by `verifyPromise`. Then, use the fact that `toast.promise` returns the promise that you pass to it, and `await` it to get the `res` object. No more `then` call is needed to process that data:

```
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      const loginPromise = verifyPassword({
        username: username,
        password: values.password,
      });

      const res = await toast.promise(loginPromise, {
        loading: "Checking...",
        success: <b> Login successfully...</b>,
        error: <b> Incorrect Password </b>,
      });

      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      navigate("/profile");
    },
```